# Passing a string but getting byte attribute error to urllib.request.read

Tags: python, xml, urllib

I am trying to read an XML file from the Yahoo finance API. So far, I've tried the following:

```
 from xml.dom.minidom import parse
 #Start Get Employees
        xml = urllib.request.urlopen('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.stocks%20where%20symbol%3D%22wfc%22&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys')
        dom = parse(xml.read())
        numemployees = dom.getElementsByTagName('FullTimeEmployees')
        numemployees = name[0].firstChild.nodeValue
 #End Get Employees
```

However, this raises an exception:

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I think this is because if it doesn't recognize the string, it assumes I'm passing a byte pattern. However, I am passing a string so I don't know what the problem is here.

Full Stack Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1487, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\Desktop\dm\Mail Server Finder\mailserverfinder.py", line 25, in getServers
    dom = parse(xml.read())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1960, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 913, in parse
    result = builder.parseFile(file)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 204, in parseFile
    buffer = file.read(16*1024)
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: The `xml.read()` call isn't failing. What's the full backtrace? Where is `parse` coming from?

Comment: Parse is from this: from xml.dom.minidom import parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`xml.dom.minidom.parse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.parse) is excepting a file-like object, not a `bytes` or `str`, as stated in its documentation:

> xml.dom.minidom.parse(filename_or_file[, parser[, bufsize]])
>
> Return a Document from the given input. filename_or_file may be either
>     a file name, or a file-like object.

So you just need to do this:

```
dom = parse(xml)
```

Because the `http.client.HTTPResponse` object returned by `urlopen` is file-like.

Answer (score 0):

Kyle, sorry but your example isn't clear enough. I think this is what you expected to do.

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

employees = urllib.urlopen('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.stocks%20where%20symbol%3D%22wfc%22&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys').read()
dom = parseString(employees)
numemployees = dom.getElementsByTagName('FullTimeEmployees')
numemployees = numeemployees[0].firstChild.nodeValue
```